# Harry Potter and The Order of Phoenix fanfic with an alternate story line with a love angle between Harry and Hermione

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Many years back (more than 10) I came across a PDF for *Harry Potter and The Order Of Phoenix*. It had a completely different story line. If I remember correctly, in the first chapter Harry was meddling around in the garden thinking about his own physical growth and over the course of the book there was a love angle between him and Hermione. Some portion that I can recollect from the first chapter is about a snake Harry encounters in the garden and the snake is not in a really good shape and Harry takes care of it. Rest of the year in the school was completely different too, Sirius doesn't die as per the story and it's a gradual build up to his and Hermione's relationship.

I have never been able to find that PDF again.

Comment: This is most likely a fan fiction so I've added the relevant tag. Can you remember anything else about this though? What, other than the love angle and first chapter, happens? Is the rest of the year completely different too? How? How many years is "many years back"? You can [edit] this and anything else into your question should you remember anything else.

Comment: I am honestly not able to recollect much on the story line but I was watching the final part of the movie and remembered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is "[Harry Potter and the Psychic Serpent](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/288212/1/Harry-Potter-and-the-Psychic-Serpent)" as per [Harry Potter Fan Fiction where The Order of the Phoenix is a medal and Harry becomes a Griffin Animagus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178027/), which I answered a few years back.

> In Harry’s fifth year at Hogwarts, he gets a snake with the Sight; Hermione’s torn between Ron and Harry, who's torn between her and Ginny, who's torn between him and Draco Malfoy, who's torn between her and loyalty to his father. Voldemort may be trying to recruit Harry now instead of killing him, and there are giants and house elves and a Duelling Club.

The plot points match. He starts doing yard work and develops physically. He meets a snake who he becomes friends with. Things heat up between him and Hermione when she comes to visit at the Dursleys, and wears a bikini to sun herself.

My answer there was not accepted, but there is an accepted answer at [HP fan-fiction where an Imperiused Dudley jumps off a building](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163509/hp-fan-fic-where-an-imperiused-dudley-jumps-off-a-building?rq=1).

Comment: I will go through the content and get back. Thanks a lot. I just had to get this back as I was not able to recollect it entirely. Thanks once again mate.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for.